# Is there an example site that uses navigator.serial?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that Chrome Canary has an implementation of a web serial api at `navigator.serial`, and I'm interested in looking at it. The previous API for serial ports `chrome.serial` implements listener callbacks, while this new API seems to deal in streams.

I've looked at the example at https://wicg.github.io/serial/#usage-example, but it seems pretty bare bones.

```
<html>
<script>
var port;
var buffy = new ArrayBuffer(1);
var writer;
buffy[0]=10;
const test = async function () {
    const requestOptions = {
      // Filter on devices with the Arduino USB vendor ID.
      //filters: [{ vendorId: 0x2341 }],
    };

    // Request an Arduino from the user.
    port = await navigator.serial.requestPort(requestOptions);

    // Open and begin reading.
    await port.open({ baudrate: 115200 });
    //const reader = port.in.getReader();
    const reader = port.readable.getReader();
    writer = port.writable.getWriter();
    //const writer = port.writable.getWriter();
    //writer.write(buffy);
    while (true) {
      const {done, data} = await reader.read();
      if (done) break;
      console.log(data);
    }
} // end of function
</script>
<button onclick="test()">Click It</button>
</html>
```

I'd like to find a working example, and eventually find a way to migrate an app from `chrome.serial` to `navigator.serial`

Comment: Tip: you can search github -> https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=%22navigator+serial%22&type=Code (it may take some work to dig through the clutter, but it's a resource...)

Comment: Thanks. I had tried `"navigator.serial"` instead of `"navigator serial"`. With a dot between the two words I got all sorts of useless results.

Answer (score 0):

Hey battling this as well. To enable this 'experimental api', open Canary, and punch this into the url: chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

Enable that feature. Now you can use it.