# Beginner problem with chrome navigator.serial

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, navigator

I am working on use of serial port access with chrome browser, using "navigator.serial".

My initial experiment is based on a prior posting to stackoverflow:

[Is there an example site that uses navigator.serial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192738/is-there-an-example-site-that-uses-navigator-serial)

I have duplicated the code example referenced above, and have made the required configuration change #enable-experimental-web-platform-features, again as described above.

I am doing this all on Ubuntu 18.04. There are two USB serial ports attached to the machine, and I have verified using gtkterm that I can send and receive data between the two ports.

From the example given (code duplicated below), I find that I can open the serial port and establish a "reader", and the step await reader.read() does wait until an incoming character appears on the serial port, but at this point the variabler/object "data" remains undefined.
Two questions/issues:

1. What am I doing wrong that leaves "data" undefined? I added an alert() dialog box that pops up once `const {done, data} = await reader.read();` proceeds, however, the dialog box says that "data" is at that point undefined. Is data a promise that I am failing to wait to be fulfilled?
2. I have not been able to find a (hopefully self-contained) reference on the methods and members of the classes involved (i.e., reader.read() and reader.write() are methods available to my object "readeer"; where can I find a list of available methods, and the properties of these?

Here is a copy of the code (small web page) that was obtained from the year-ago posting above:

```
<html>
<script>
var port;
var buffy = new ArrayBuffer(1);
var writer;
buffy[0]=10;
const test = async function () {
    const requestOptions = {
      // Filter on devices with the Arduino USB vendor ID.
      //filters: [{ vendorId: 0x2341 }],
    };

    // Request an Arduino from the user.
    port = await navigator.serial.requestPort(requestOptions);

    // Open and begin reading.
    await port.open({ baudrate: 115200 });
    //const reader = port.in.getReader();
    const reader = port.readable.getReader();
    writer = port.writable.getWriter();
    //const writer = port.writable.getWriter();
    //writer.write(buffy);
    while (true) {
      const {done, data} = await reader.read();
      if (done) break;
      console.log(data);
    }
} // end of function
</script>
<button onclick="test()">Click It</button>
</html>
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and managed to solve it.

Change

```
const {done, data} = await reader.read();
```

To

```
const {value, done} = await reader.read();
```

The example where you got this from (and a few others) were wrong, params around the wrong way.
Also, not too sure why but when I used

```
const {data, done} = await reader.read();
```

it did not work either, it did not like the var data.

Documentation on navigator.serial is not great. Here are some links to help

The API (note this is draft and does not exactly match the Chrome implementation)
https://wicg.github.io/serial/

port.readable.getReader() is a ReadableStream

https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#readablestream

that uses ReadableStreamDefaultReader which is defined as

```
dictionary ReadableStreamDefaultReadResult {
    any value;
    boolean done;
};
```

https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#readablestreamdefaultreader

An explainer
https://github.com/WICG/serial/blob/gh-pages/EXPLAINER.md

A tutorial
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/web-serial

Chromium tracker
https://goo.gle/fugu-api-tracker

The Web Serial API work item
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=884928